# Is there a way to slide between Activities without the black gap?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an Android app, and switch between activities with a slide, when the previous activity slides out to the right, and the new activity comes in the left.

I can do somethibg like this, with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_ltr, R.anim.out_ltr);
```

Where the `in_ltr.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="700"
    />
</set>
```

And the `out_ltr.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="500"
    />
</set>
```

It's almost perfect, but a small black gap appers between the two activity during the animation. You can see it here on [YouTube](http://youtu.be/Ta1aWMSzex4).

I've tried anything I found in the Google in the last hour, but nothing seems to remove that gap. Is it possible to remove that gap?

Thanks!

Comment: use fadi in and fade out effect with it too...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I was very, very stupid.

I changed the `duration` to the same amount of time, and the gap disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Alpha with translate effect....

Try This...

**slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_cubic">
   <translate
      android:fromXDelta="0%"
      android:toXDelta="100%"
      android:duration="400" />
   <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.3"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two file in res/anim folder.

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <translate 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
              android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
              android:toXDelta="0%p">
        </translate>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <translate
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
             android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
             android:toXDelta="-100%p">
      </translate>
```

And write the following code in onCreate() method of next activity that you pass through the Intent.

```
            overridePendingTransition(r.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

hope it will remove your space

Answer (score 0):

Try this: create a RootActivity.java and extend it in your activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RootActivity extends Activity {
    int onStartCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onStartCount = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) // 1st time
        {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
        } else // already created so reverse animation
        { 
            onStartCount = 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        if (onStartCount > 1) {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);
        } else if (onStartCount == 1) {
            onStartCount++;
        }

    }
}
```

add these animations to anim folder:

anim_slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

anim_slide_in_right.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

anim_slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

anim_slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below item into your AppTheme

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`